# Dual boot: Black screen after purple screen with logo

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, nvidia

I have `Ubuntu 14.04` installed along `Windows 8.1` running with `GRUB2` in a `MSI GE60`, `i7` with an `nVidia GeForce GTX` card.

Out of the blue, today when I try to run Ubuntu, after the purple screen with the Ubuntu logo and the loading animation, I'm just shown a black screen. Nothing loads.

- I tried entering TTY7, but I couldn't
- I tried running failsafeX, but I got the "fatal error, screen not found" error.
- I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/755688/561345) for the above error, but it didn't work
- I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/111298/561345), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/450546/561345), but didn't work neither.

What else could it be?